# Present all VOIP apps on device to user

Tags: android, android-intent

If I do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email.getAddress());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, email.getSubject());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email.getBody());
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

the app will bring up a selection of all apps that can send email. How can I do the same with VOIP? That is, not specify a particular VOIP app, but bring up all the VOIP apps on the device, e.g. Skype, Viber, Whatsapp for the user to select.

Comment: Why VOIP and not the phone dialer as well?

Comment: Because the user may be in an area where wireless is available but cellular signal is not.

Answer (score 0):

Activity/Intents have built in functionality for telephone and email, but strangely not for VOIP, so having to do this by hand, so to speak. You can find a package like so:

```
// com.google.android.talk/.SigningInActivity m=0x108000}                                   
// com.skype.raider/.Main m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null                                  
// com.viber.voip/.WelcomeActivity m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null                         
// com.whatsapp/.Main m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null                                      
private static String HANGOUTS_PACKAGE_STRING = "com.google.android.talk";                  
private static String SKYPE_PACKAGE_STRING = "com.skype.raider";                            
private static String VIBER_PACKAGE_STRING = "com.viber.voip";                              
private static String WHATASPP_PACKAGE_STRING = "com.whatsapp";                             

Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(VIBER_PACKAGE_STRING);
```

Note that Hangouts is not supported anymore.